# NodeWebkit + CKEditor Crashing app in OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, ckeditor, node-webkit, html-encode

I am using Nodewebkit for creating a simple Desktop application and I have integrated CKEditor in it.

Currently facing some issues with CKEditor in app in "MAC only" which crashes app(Closes app currently).

Steps to reproduce bug:

- Open CKEditor in app
- Type few words and make it bold
- After press of two enter keys, it closes app (Crashes).
  This is happening when user clicks on Bold/Italic/Underline Icon only and also happends only when .app file is created.

While testing locally by running GULP, it works without crashing application.

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Update:  App will crash only if HTML Encoding is used. But if HTML Encoding is not done, then it shows special symbols for enter key pressed.

Comment: I am not able to get error log, because when I tried using https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Crash-dump It did not create a file for me in BreakPad folder and It does not throw error when I run it from gulp. So not able to get error logs. If be any means I can get error logs, that would be great

Comment: 1 more thing, app crashes only when HTML Encoding is used.